# Specific git-dir directory shouldn't be listed as "untracked"

Tags: git

For some reasons, I want to create a local repository with a custom dir name instead of `.git`, I used the global option `--git-dir` and `--work-tree` (see https://git-scm.com/docs/git) also configurable with env vars:

```
export GIT_DIR=".customgitdir"
export GIT_WORK_TREE="."
```

Then I created the repo:

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in XXXXXXXXX/.customgitdir/
```

Then I ran `git status`:

```
$ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    .customgitdir/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

You can see the local repo directory listed as "untracked files" which is a problem when using `git add .` afterwards.

When using the default directory `.git`, it logically doesn't appear in the `git status` command's output. Why isn't it the same with a custom directory name ?

Comment: Skipping over `.git` is hard-coded into the source, regardless of `$GIT_DIR`. There is no built in code to skip over `$GIT_DIR`, just `.git`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a global .gitignore file, which is a list of rules for ignoring files in every Git repository on your computer like so:

`git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global`

And the contents of `~/.gitignore_global` would be:
`.customgitdir`

While you are at it, other useful excludes for the file are mentioned here: https://gist.github.com/octocat/9257657

Also, checkout https://www.gitignore.io and https://github.com/github/gitignore